# javafx-2 applet doesn't update gui when called from javascript

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, applet, javafx-2, updates

I'm trying to invoke a method from javascript object which in turn calls a the following java method :

```
public void loadPicture(final String absolutePath) {

  System.out.println("loadPicture " + absolutePath);
  Image dbimage;
  dbimage = new Image(absolutePath, 100.0d, 100.0d, false, false);
  final ImageView dbImageView = new ImageView();
  dbImageView.setImage(dbimage);


  Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        System.out.println("hbox children : "+hbox.getChildren().size());
        hbox.getChildren().add(dbImageView);
        System.out.println("hbox children : "+hbox.getChildren().size());
        //test
        //logger.debug(" aggiunto "+absolutePath);

        DropPictures.getPicturesNames().add(absolutePath);

      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("eccezione :" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
      }

    }
  });

}
```

In javascript the method invocation is :

```
var a = document.getElementById(myDivId);
a.loadPicture();
```

I've traced the execution and the above method doesn't throw any exception,but it is run cause i see the output in java console, but the applet doesn't show the picture.
I've used Platform.runLater to update the GUI in the javafx thread, still no update is performed.